# Need a method to embed rdlc designer in web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services, rdlc

We are working on a web asp.net MVC based project that needs a web-based report builder. We have worked with the rdlc reports before, but, the designer is available only at design time. Is it possible to embed the rdl report designer into a web page? The user should be able to design, save and use the reports through the web page. If no, then are there any alternatives? preferably opensource or free. Also we are open to paid options if they are worth it.

We have tried searching on the topic but haven't been able to find a direction.

Kindly suggest